# Add visual difference for negative code examples

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, markdown

I see that often someone makes *negative* examples and marks them either with *//DON'T* or similar. I think that is not enough; one should be able to visually tell positive from negative examples. For example, from [this documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/496/multidimensional-and-jagged-arrays)

```
// valid
String[][] employeeGraph = new String[30][];

// invalid
int[][] unshapenMatrix = new int[][10];
```

Or [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/2832/iterating-over-arrays):

```
//DO
for( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++ ) {
    numbers[i] += 1; //or this: numbers[i] = numbers[i] + 1; or numbers[i]++;
}

//DON'T
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    numbers[i] += 1;
}
```

The proposition is that on the right side of the code block a red line is being displayed to mark the code block as a counterexample. Possible design and Markdown syntax:

```
<!-- bad-code -->

    //DON'T
    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        numbers[i] += 1;
    }
```

displays as

[image: Displaying a bad code example]

Comment: perhaps suppport for the Diff language in SO markdown will be enought . Like https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/362545