# Should we strike through examples of invalid code?

Tags: discussion, documentation, code-formatting

I've recently seen examples of invalid code on Documentation, used to explain how not to do things or what is not possible.

> This is not well-formed: <strike>`<person></person first-name="John"/>`</strike>

This example points out that it is not allowed putting atrributes in a closing tag in XML. Apparently, the author has decided to write it strike-through so no one thinks this is a working example.

This is probably meaningful, but on the other hand, I personally think that you can't read the code as good as if it haven't been striken through.

Should we strike through all invalid examples to clarify they are invalid examples or shouldn't we to make them more readable? Or are there any other ways to mark invalid code?

Comment: Striking through makes a lot of sense for something that is essentially *encouraging* people to copy and paste code from it. Minimizing ambiguity has to be prioritized over readability. It isn't terribly important to read broken code anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray This is also quite my point of view - I would personally prefer striking through wrong code. +1 for pointing out the encouragement to copy ;)

Comment: @CodyGray and the others who voted up the comment: I'll put this in an answer, if you don't mind (so the question has at least one)

Comment: Wait, is the point that striking through encourages people to copy and paste, or encourages them not to; in all of my editors simply copy and pasting removes all formatting (bold, strike, ect) and doesn't inconvenience me at either way

Comment: @StevenByrne The point was that striking through an invalid example will probably discourage readers from directly copy-pasting it because it doesn't look like normal code you would just copy and paste. Of course, if you wanted to copy this invalid example for whatever purpose, striking through won't prevent you from doing this. Anyway, this was a question regarding the shut-down project Documentation, so I voted to close my question yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes, we should strike through those examples.

As CodyGray pointed out [in their comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328961/should-we-strike-through-examples-of-invalid-code?noredirect=1#comment370664_328961), StackOverflow Documentation is *encouraging people* to copy code from it.

As we do not want people to copy broken code, we should strike through examples of invalid code and prefer minimized ambiguity over perfectly readable code.

Comment: [The author of this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328632/add-visual-difference-for-negative-code-examples) also wants a way to show invalid code; however, they propose a documentation syntax extension to have a better way to achieve this.