# Code examples that shows bad code should be highlighted in some way

Tags: feature-request, documentation

I think it would be a good idea to have a different style for incorrect code examples. Maybe have a reddish background instead of the usual gray.

In the questions section I guess it's rare that you would need to post incorrect code. But in the documentation it may serve a purpose. Here is one example I found that contains code that no one should copy and use.

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/38/using-statement/327/gotcha-returning-the-resource-which-you-are-disposing#t=201609191334587592686

Comment: Slight red background, probably, would not do any harm. Of course, it should be clear from the context, but this is same as syntax highlight.

Comment: `user-select: none;`

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328632/3888450

Comment: I think this is a good idea, but what would the markup to make this look like?

Comment: Related Q: Is there any Markdown flavor that has support for this, and/or is there any related topic on https://talk.commonmark.org/ perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

A color coded code block would pop more than a grey one.

Leave it as is.  A slight red isn't sufficient to defend hostile code in a code block, or even bad code.  A bandage over a gaping wound is not an incremental improvement.

Bad code should be clearly bad in context and in content, with the context saying bad code is coming, and the code itself clearly marked up with comments explaining why it is bad.  That is sufficient to deal with bad code, and once done a slight red coloring is no longer needed.

A subtle formatting change would imply that that is enough, that bad code that is marked with that formatting change doesn't need to be highlighted with text context and embedded comments.  It leads posters astray, and doesn't do enough to mitigate harm.

Answer (score -2):

Syntax highlighting is [implemented with an external engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109), whose [documentation](https://github.com/google/code-prettify#how-can-i-customize-the-colors-and-styles-of-my-code) says:

> **How can I customize the colors and styles of my code?**
>
> Prettify adds `<span>` with `class`es describing the kind of code. You can create CSS styles to matches these classes.

It might be possible to add CSS magic to change the style of specially marked code blocks.

However, styling does not survive copying/pasting into a plain text file.
(*Nobody* would blindly copy code from the first Google search result, but we also care about those nobodies, don't we?)
So it would be a better idea to add a big, fat comment to the wrong code:

```c#
// THIS IS WRONG!
using (var db = new DBContext())
{
    return db;
} // <-- db gets disposed here
```

Comment: What kind of weirdo copy-pastes *the entire document* and only then trims it to leave vaguely runnable code? That is a special sort of aggressive stupidity that I am quite happy allowing to run its course, preferably with someone nearby to record the fireworks for posterity. Therefore (leaving aside red-green colorblindness for the moment) color-coded or otherwise distinguished code blocks seem useful on the same basis as the code blocks themselves: they tell you what chunk of hieroglyphics to blindly copy-paste, naturally.